# Jquery/JS - hide Div in modal when select options changes

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, hide

I'm trying to hide some textareas on my modal when opening it and when changing the select options, hide or show a div containing all textareas.

I've tried to explain all JS code here : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z114zjj6/)

I'm not saying the code is pretty, I'll be happy to have some advices about it.

I wished I could link more code on this page, but i'm afraid I don't know where the issue is =/ I guess the only interesting thing is the javascript/jquery code ?

```
$('#create-popup').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    if (!$("#act_origin").val()) { //apparently when opening, the val is undefined
        $("#origin-display").hide();
    }
    //function when select is changing. 
    function origin() {
        if ($("#act_origin").val() == 1 ) { //HORSPAF
            $("#origin-display").hide();            
        } else  {
            $("#origin-display").show();
        }
    };
});
```

I've tried also (when reading other answers)

```
if ($("#act_origin option:selected").text() === "HORSPAF")
```

and

```
$("#create-popup").find('#origin-display').hide();
```

I might use them wrong, but it doesn't seem to work either =(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the modal, already it has a value. So your below check doesn't work:

```
//apparently when opening, the val is undefined
```

Replace the if condition with:

```
$("#origin-display").hide();
```

Or better, add a `hidden` class to it.

And since it is a `<select>`, add a default option of empty value.

```
<option></option>
```

And the below code is not attached to any event handler. It has to be attached to the `<select>`'s `change` event. So make it this way:

```
// function when select is changing.    
function origin() {
    if ($("#act_origin").val() == 1 ) { //HORSPAF
        $("#origin-display").hide();
    } else  {
        $("#origin-display").show();
    }
}
$("#act_origin").change(origin);
```

And finally, give this CSS to fit everything in the modal window:

```
#origin-display {overflow: hidden;}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qc2xy5qe/**